# What is the proper way to fetch data for a global layout component in Next JS

Tags: reactjs, layout, next.js

I'm having some trouble finding a solution for how to handling a global header for my website in Next.js. Most tutorials demonstrate a Layout.js file that accepts in children and wraps the entire application but data it receives is hard coded in the Header component itself rather then being fetch from some api. I've seen some answers on here that recommend using getInitialProps but that it is an outdated way of doing things. The other option might be using Client Side Data fetching but that also has some downsides in terms of SEO and seeing a loading state.

```js
import '../styles/globals.css';
import Layout from '../components/Layout';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    return (
        <Layout>
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </Layout>
    );
}

export default MyApp;

// Fetch data and pass it to Layout component as props
```

Comment: Can you explain more about the data you want to use in `Layout` component and provide the `Layout` component code.

Comment: did you find solution?